# using list on postgresql JSON type with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I am using pyramid with sqlalchemy, pyramid_tm and postgresql to test this.

```
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
Base = declarative_base()


class MyList(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    lst = Column(JSON)
```

I am using postgresql 9.3+ and using JSON type. When i do this

```
mylst = MyList(lst=[])
```

i can see empty [] list being created on database as well, and

```
def view(request):
    mylst = DBSession.query(MyList).get(1)
    mylst.lst.append('45')
    print(DBSession.is_active, DBSession.is_modified(mylst))
```

i can see ['45'] in database, and print returns

```
True, True
```

continuing from above [edit] on next request (above is already committed)

```
def view(request):
    mylst = DBSession.query(MyList).get(1)
    mylst.lst.append('65')
    print(DBSession.is_active, DBSession.is_modified(mylst))
```

The db wont get updated, it is still ['45'] and print returns

```
True, False
```

Am i doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default, SQLAlchemy only tracks changes of the value itself, which works "as expected" for simple values, such as ints and strings:

```
alice.name = "Alice"
alice.age = 8
```

It also works when you assign a new value to a column of a "complex type", such as dict or list:

```
alice.toys = ['doll', 'teddy bear']
```

However, SQLAlchemy does not notice a change if you modify one of the elements in the list, or append/remove a value:

```
alice.toys[0] = 'teapot'
alice.toys.append('lego bricks')
```

To make this work you can either make sure you assign a new list each time:

```
toys = alice.toys[:]  # makes a "clone" of the existing list
toys[0] = 'teapot'
toys.append('lego bricks')
alice.toys = toys
```

Or have a read of the [Mutation Tracking](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/mutable.html) chapter in SQLAlchemy docs to see how you can subclass a list or a dict so they track modifications of their elements.

Also, since you mentioned you're using Postgres - there's a dedicated [`ARRAY`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.array) type in Postgres which you can use instead of `JSON` if all you need is to store lists. However, what is said above about the mutation tracking applies to columns of `ARRAY` type too.

Comment: @Sergey may you kindly elaborate how to change `Column(JSON)` to `Column(ARRAY)`? It seems I have to also specify the type. But how do I define a array that can contain dictionaries?

Answer (score 2):

You could flag an instance as modified manually

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.attributes import flag_modified

def view(session):
    mylst = Session.query(MyList).get(1)
    mylst.lst.append('45')
    flag_modified(mylst, 'lst') # flag its `lst' attribute is modified
    print(Session.is_active, Session.is_modified(mylst))
    # (True, True)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try `DBSession.flush()` after `mylst.lst.append('45')`. This allows you to update the DB prior to pyramid_tm doing the commit.

More information can be found here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html#flushing

Comment: the second portion is after commit, sorry was not that clearer

Comment: Ah ok, so this is a subsequent request. I imagine there must be an error being emitted in the console. How verbose is the setting of your SQLAlchemy warnings in development.ini? You can also flush ahead of time to see if any errors are emitted.